# How to use positional parameter in script when it is interval

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line, sh

I have a positional parameter A-B it's interval and I need to use this interval to print lines from a file. In example $./File.sh 5-10 so I need my script to print lines of a file between 5 and 10.

Comment: Have you tried anything for this? Do you know how to (ignoring your argument) print an interval of lines from a file at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A POSIX-compliant solution: use the built-in `read` command to split the range.

```
IFS=- read a b <<EOF
$1
EOF
```

In `bash`, you have some simpler options.

1. `IFS=- read a b <<< "$1"`
2. `[[ $1 =~ ^(.*)-(.*)$ ]] && a=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} b=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}`

None of these involve forking new processes to run external programs.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have a file with 20 lines and you want to print lines 5-15...The below command is how you can accomplish this.

```
sed -n '5,15p' {name_of_file}
```

Replace {name_of_file} with the actual filename.

Now I am not going to write out your entire script but you can take $1 (5-15) and parse that data...for example.

```
fieldOne=$(echo $1 | awk -F"-" '{print $1}') #This will equal 5
fieldTwo=$(echo $1 | awk -F"-" '{print $2}') #This will equal 15
```

Comment: There is only one parameter $1 (5-15)

Comment: There. updated my answer to show you how to parse $1

Comment: Or assume the user specified the range correctly: `awk "${1/-/,}p" …` (replace the dash with comma; add `p`).  On the whole, though, it is better to assume you've forgotten how to write the range and you should validate it.